# Cannot edit recordset after setting table Connect property, Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I've added a screen that allows changing tables Connect property so that users can change databases.

Here's the values I change:

```
ODBC;Description=####;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=SERVER2008\MSSQLSERVER2008;UID=####
;PWD=####;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=####
```

After doing so, this piece of code:

```
With Me.Child5.Form.Recordset 'linked tabled
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        .Edit
        !Allow = False
        !ReadOnly = False
        .Update
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Raises "error '3027': Cannot update. Database or object is read-only'.

I should say that before changing the Connect property everything works just fine with regards to this piece of code. Also, even after changing the Connect property, changing information in other forms bounded to other tables, changes do take effect with no error raised, so that database is obviously not read-only.

Any ideas? thanks

EDIT: I also called `RefreshLink` after setting `Connect`, and changes in other tables actually did take effect in the new database.

Comment: After you updated the `.Connect` property of the TableDef object did you call the `.RefreshLink` method to complete the process?

Comment: Yes I did. I also checked that changes (where I had no error) were made to the right database...

Comment: ...and the affected Forms are all closed (not just hidden) when you change the table link?

Comment: All but the from that makes the changes, but it is bounded to a local table that is not edited.

Answer (score 0):

The UID you are giving to SQL Server in your ODBC connection string is a read-only UID.  Your UID is a db-owner UID, so you can make edits.

In addition, if the recordset is created with a JOIN in the SQL statement you will almost always be prevented from editing the recordset.